# How to bind angular4 at front end and python at backend?

Tags: python, angular

How do I bind the front end and back-end where angular 4 is at front-end and python is at back-end. I have attached the .ts file, html file as well as python .py file using the POST method...I am really stuck...please help...

> Angular frontend(HTML)

```
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
              <h4 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Add server info</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
              <form>
                  <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="txtDevice" class="control-label">Server URL:</label>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="info.device" id="txtDevice">
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="txtIP" class="control-label">IP Address:</label>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="info.ip" id="txtIP">
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="txtUsername" class="control-label">Username:</label>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="info.username" id="txtUsername">
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="txtPassword" class="control-label">Password:</label>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="info.password" id="txtPassword">
                  </div>
                  <!-- <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="txtPort" class="control-label">Port:</label>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="info.port" id="txtPort">
                  </div> -->
              </form>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
              <!-- <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button> -->
              <!-- <button ng-show="showAdd" id="btnAdd" ng-click="addMachine()" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Add machine</button> -->

              <button id="btnAdd" (click)="searchServer(serverDetails)" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Search</button>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

> Angular(.ts)

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { ServerListingComponent } from '../server-listing/server-listing.component';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { SessionStorage, LocalStorage, LocalStorageService } from 'ngx-webstorage';
import { URLSearchParams } from '@angular/http';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule }   from '@angular/forms';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-enter-details',
  templateUrl: './enter-details.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./enter-details.component.css']
})

export class EnterDetailsComponent implements OnInit {

  url;
  serverDetails = {
    URL:'',
    ipAddress:'',
    username:'',
    password:''
  };

  constructor( public http: Http,public router: Router, public storage: LocalStorageService) {
    this.url = this.storage.retrieve('url');

   }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  searchServer(serverDetails){
   debugger
   this.http.get(this.url + "details?filter[where][URL]=" + this.serverDetails.URL.toString() + "&filter[where][ipAddress]=" 
                 + this.serverDetails.ipAddress.toString() + "&filter[where][username]=" + this.serverDetails.username.toString() 
                 + "&filter[where][password]=" + this.serverDetails.password.toString())
   .map(res => res.json())
   .subscribe(isPresent => {
     debugger
     this.router.navigate(['/serverListing']);
   });
}
}
```

> Python API

import sys
    import paramiko
    import getpass 
    import os
    import webbrowser
    from flask_api import FlaskAPI
    from flask import Flask
    from pymongo import MongoClient

```
ip=''
username=''
password=''
path=''

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def output():
  return ('/enter-details.html')

@app.route('/details', methods = ['POST'])
def showMachineList():
  remote_conn_pre=paramiko.SSHClient()
  remote_conn_pre.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
  remote_conn_pre.connect(ip, username=username, password=password, look_for_keys=False, allow_agent=False)
  print(remote_conn_pre)
# print()
  ftp = remote_conn_pre.open_sftp()
  ftp.get(path, 'create_user.js')
  ftp.close()
  webbrowser.open_new(os.getcwd()+"/create_user.js") 
  return (remote_conn_pre)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't 'bind' the front-end to the back-end as Angular's sole purpose is to sit on the client side whilst your backend is server side. The two should be separate.

What you'll need to do to is run both servers at the same time, and use POST/GET requests to pass information to and from your backend.